# Nginx two angular apps

Tags: nginx

I'd like to add separated angular app under a specific path (the path should be at the end of an URL to be matched) - I want to keep both versions which are current and a new one but the new should only be available under the specified path. I tried using alias + try_files. My config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /dir/project1
  server_name ...;

  index index.html;

  location ~ /path {
    alias /dir/project2
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

The thing is that when try_files fires up, it takes the path from the root directive - not from the alias. How to fix it? I can only add I cannot use proxy_pass here and root instead of the alias does not work either as it adds paths etc.

Comment: You are missing a couple of `;`s, but I am assuming that's just a typo in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` directive works differently when placed inside a regular expression location, but you should probably be using a prefix location anyway. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Also, the use of `alias` and `try_files` together can cause problems (see [this long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97)).

You are rewriting the URI to `/index.html` which is the wrong application, and should instead be `/path/index.html`.

Try:

```
location ^~ /path {
    alias /dir/project2;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^ /path/index.html last;
    }
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Richard thanks. Using the provided config I was able to read index.html properly, but some problems still persist. One thing is that this location works only when the path is at the beginning URL e.x. domain.com/path but not for domain.com/something/path. And the second thing is that it loads properly index.html but not styles and js files as /path is not present later for these requests in the URL. But perhaps it might be app problem?

Comment: Settings base url path for angular app build fixed loading assets.

Comment: Yes, `base` is a good solution for relocating the assets. You can use a regular expression location, but that only complicates the alias. Is `/somthing/path` always going to be a route and never a static file? In which case, you can add another location (e.g. `location ~ /path { rewrite ^ /path/index.html last; }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Adding another location did not help as using URL /{something}/path returns 403. {something} should be dynamic as it can be freely modified. So what I want to achieve is domain.com/{something} should run the old app but domain.com/{something}/path should run the new app - same when {something} is not present at all (which works with the first location solution).